# Deinstantize the instances [instance] and [instances]!

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

Why do we need both [instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/instances) and [instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/instance)? The questions look the same and the tag wiki for [instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/instances) is very minimal:

> a specific realization of any object.

It currently has 352 questions, and so I would like to request that we merge [instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/instances) into [instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/instance).

**EDIT**

Well then I guess the world had decided to try to BURN ALL [instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/instances) OF [instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/instance) AND [instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/instances) TO THE GROUND.

Comment: Do we even need these tags at all?

Comment: @nhahtdh I think that instance is a good tag to have because alot of questions are about class instance methods/variables/other things. If you search the [instance] tag you get good questions all related to class instances.

Comment: Make [instances] an instance of [instance]!

Comment: @Tunaki +1, but how about "Reinstantiate [instances] as an instance of [instance]"? :)

Comment: Thank you @Tunaki for the title. I have changed it now. Hopefully more people will look at it.

Comment: @nhahtdh: Can someone be an expert for instance? Of course! So we need the tag, definitely!

Comment: I came here for the title. Did not disappoint

Comment: We have to go **deeper**.

Comment: The tag instances is already made a synonym of instance.

Comment: Nowadays there are >5k questions with [tag:instance]

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Nobody is an expert on "instances". Nobody searches for those questions. That word never clarifies anything.

Burninate both tags.

Comment: Will someone add a [tag:burninate-request] on the question, should I do that or do we wait until this answer has enough votes? Not sure how it works.

Comment: I don't know either. I think the burnination process is onerous and nobody should participate. The SE team needs to deliver something that wastes less time.

Comment: I'm gonna wait until this has 15+ upvotes then I'll add the tag

Comment: -1. Have you ever developed in java? Anybody could be an expert about class instances, and could help people about problems with their instance.

Comment: @Joehot200 is that a joke? I honestly can't tell. 90% of Java developers are experts at "class instances". This is a very basic language feature. Who would ever subscribe to the "instances" tag?!

Comment: @usr Nobody did subscribe to the instances tag, there are 6 subscribers for the instance tag however. <sarcasm>So it is very popular</sarcasm>