# Nuke and blacklist all of the tags for fundamental programming concepts

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

See this meta question:

- [Make [instances] an instance of [instance]!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303954/make-instances-an-instance-of-instance)

My initial response is the same as [this answer to that question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/304148/173497):

> Nobody is an expert on "instances". Nobody searches for those questions. That word never clarifies anything.
>
> Burninate both tags.

Given the above sentiment, we should burninate all similar tags; some examples:

- [class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/class)
- [constants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/constants)
- [function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/function)
- [global-variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/global-variables)
- [scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scope)
- [semantics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/semantics)
- [syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/syntax)
- [variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/variables)

All of these tags are guilty of [criterion 3 in the tag removal rules](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191) but unfortunately removing these tags seems like the epitome of "pointless busywork" – there are currently 37k+ questions alone tagged *class*!

The best treatment would be to nuke all of these tags and prevent users from using them in the future.

Related questions:

- [Purpose of the [function], [method], [variable], etc. tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262984/173497)
- [Deinstantize the instances [instance] and [instances]!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303954/173497)
- [What, if any, is an appropriate use for the [loops] tag?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251139/173497)

Comment: From the criteria that you linked: "DO NOT try for a two-fer - one tag per discussion."  While not specifically noted, I'm pretty sure an eight-fer is out of bounds as well.

Comment: @tristan I figured because this is *so* far out of bounds that it's fair game. Besides, the standard burninate process would be "pointless" busywork for any of the tags I listed. 'Nuking' (i.e. admin 'mass burning') would be required to make this worthwhile.

Comment: I have to disagree with at least [tag:scope]. There are quite some usful questions properly tagged with it. The same for [tag:class]; not all languages have classes baked-in.

Comment: @Deduplicator The fact that there are useful questions in those tags doesn't mean that it's the tag that's making those questions useful.  People aren't following those tags ("scope" has a whopping 26 followers for ~9k questions), and searching on those terms can easily result in finding the relevant questions through their use of the word in the text of the question.  Nuking the tag doesn't mean deleting every question using the tag.

Comment: @Servy: Sure burning the tag does not mean killing all the questions. But I said *properly*, as in usefully, tagged with scope. And you certainly won't deny that `class`, combined with a language which doen't have those baked in, is useful?

Comment: @Deduplicator I would absolutely deny that it's a useful tag.

Comment: @Deduplicator No one is an expert in any of these concepts. Almost every question with one of these tags is a question about a particular question. There's no point in tagging all of those questions with every even-somewhat-relevant concept. Are you really claiming that [*identifier*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/identifier) is a useful tag??

Comment: I picked those two I'm fairly certain are useful. Is identifier useful? I don't think it is, but I didn't look into it any.

Comment: @Deduplicator I would agree that *class* **would** be useful were it restricted to questions about patterns related to that concept in languages that don't offer classes natively, but that's the case for only one of the top 50 questions with that tag.

Comment: Tags to my understanding are used to categorize questions. A question can have multiple tags, it seems to me that the only thing that is made a problem of here is that some tags don't work as the **only** tag on a question. Take syntax as an example: if a question is only tagged with syntax, it is meaningless. But if something is tagged with both C# and syntax, that makes it a question specifically about C# language syntax. that still makes syntax a useful tag, its just not useful to follow.

Comment: @Gimby None of these tags are *adding* any value on their own. That seems evident because it's hard to think of anything that would be *lost* were these tags to be removed. What does *syntax* really add? Or *semantics*? Even *instance* or *class* – surely better tags than *syntax* or *semantics* – [seem to be un-controversially ripe for removal](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303954/deinstantize-the-instances-instance-and-instances).

Comment: We should include [tag:default] and [tag:default-value] in this list. Some context: the tag wikis are nearly identical, so they refer to the same thing; edit suggestions introducing such tags are being rejected ([\[1\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285404/4642212), [\[2\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/380959/4642212#comment675425_380959)). Both tags fail every burnination criterion except _maybe_ the on-topicness — yes, there is some overlap between programming and the concept of defaults…

Answer (score 18):

These tags are all very well suited to having a developer just remove the tags.

There are *very* few followers to these tags, so clearly people aren't using them as a means of discovering new content.  The followers per question rate of these tags is astonishingly low.

These terms are generally going to be used in the question title/body, meaning that people searching for these concepts can still find the relevant questions, but as these concepts are just so *very broad*, it's not really useful to be searching for *just* these concepts either.

These tags also aren't well suited for manual cleanup either.  Not only are there *very* large numbers of questions tagged with many of these tags, but, more importantly:

- They're not a strong indicator of low quality content that could get cleaned up along with the tag removal.
- They're not tags that need to be disambiguated and replaced with one of many possible alternate tags
- They really shouldn't be the *only* tag a question is posted with.