# How to deal with tag synonyms for generic tags like [scope]?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonym-process

I came across the tag [scoping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scoping) (over 200 questions), and would like to suggest it as a synonym for [scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scope). However, I don't (and may never) have 5 points in the scope tag.

My question is, how should we deal with synonyms for these kinds of general cross-cutting tags? It seems like a poor quality tag to begin with since it is unlikely that anyone is an expert in scoping. This question ([Nuke and blacklist all of the tags for fundamental programming concepts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/304229/nuke-and-blacklist-all-of-the-tags-for-fundamental-programming-concepts)) suggests that those tags should be burninated entirely.

However, if burnination is too extreme, who is responsible for maintaining these types of tags since they don't have experts or stakeholders?

Comment: What do you mean "maintain the quality of...tags"? Questions have quality, not tags. If you see low-quality questions, then fix the questions. Honestly, I don't understand why there is all this obsession over tags when there is an overflow of crappy questions. Hint: it is not the tags that are causing the problem.

Comment: You're right. That was a poor attempt at a summary. Reworded.