# Did I use this tag correctly?

Tags: discussion, support, tags, questions, edits

I edited a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36055536/why-variable-defined-in-a-if-else-blocks-can-be-used-outside-blocks), which asked about the scope of variables, thus I used [variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/variables), since (luckily) I couldn't find something like Python-variables.

However, its wiki scares me:

> THIS IS AMBIGUOUS; USE SPECIFIC-LANGUAGE TAGS WHENEVER APPLICABLE.

so I feel a bit "guilty" now. Should I?

Comment: You did use a specific-language tag. The question is tagged [tag:python].

Comment: @CodyGray yes, I added that tag!

Comment: related (not a duplicate): http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/304229/578411

Comment: Exactly @rene, I had the feeling that this tag would be in such a list, hence my question. I am still worried.