# What is considered a meta tag and should meta tags be banned / burninated / removed?

Tags: discussion, tags, meta-tags

I notice lots of tags that seem kind of meta to me

Examples: [animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/animation), [3d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/3d), [depth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/depth), [shader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shader), [performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/performance), [2d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/2d), [sprite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sprite), [raycasting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/raycasting), [textures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/textures), [alpha-blending](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/alpha-blending), [shaders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shaders), [array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/array), [graphics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/graphics), [blending](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/blending), [frame-rate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/frame-rate), [framebuffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/framebuffer), [gpu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gpu), [memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/memory), [particles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/particles), [simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/simulator), [robotics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/robotics), [responsive-design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/responsive-design), [responsive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/responsive), [mouseover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mouseover), [rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rendering), [antialiasing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/antialiasing), [colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/colors), [color-space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/color-space), [filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/filter), [colormatrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/colormatrix), [geometry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/geometry), [texture-mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/texture-mapping), [uv-mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uv-mapping), [yuv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yuv), [coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/coordinates), [mesh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mesh), [physics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/physics), [indexing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/indexing), [copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/copy), [image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/image), [render-to-texture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/render-to-texture)

That's just the list from the first 50 questions on [webgl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webgl)

I guess I'm wondering if I understand what the point of tags. My assumption is tags are meant to help questioners find relevant answers and answerers find questions they can answer.

This [old blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/) proclaims meta-tags are a problem and describes how to tell a meta tag from a tag

> How can you tell you’re using a meta-tag? It’s easier than you might think.
>
> - If the tag can’t work as the only tag on a question, it’s probably a meta-tag. Every tag you use should be able to work, more or less, as the only tag on a question.
> - Meta-tags are actually a subset of a larger problem that I usually call dependent tags. These are tags that don’t say anything by themselves – you can’t tell what the question is about unless they’re paired with some other tag

Maybe there is disagreement on what a meta-tag is and if they are useful. Do any of the tags above fit as the *only* tag on a question? To me they don't because if they were the only tag on the question they are not useful for either someone looking for an answer nor someone looking to provide answers. Are any of the tags above not dependent on some other tag? AFAICT they are all dependent tags and therefore meta tags.

Hopefully uncontroversial examples would be [3d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/3d), [image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/image), [coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/coordinates) but to pick maybe more controversial one, take for example [texture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/texture). "texture" could be applied to questions about [metal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/metal), [opengl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opengl), [opengl-es](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opengl-es), [directx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/directx), [vulkan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vulkan), [webgl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webgl), [three.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/three.js), [unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity), [unreal-engine4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unreal-engine4), [godot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/godot) and probably 100+ other tags. It's unlikely an answerer that can answer that can answer a question in one of those APIs or libraries knows the answer for another API or library. So the tag doesn't help questioners find answers because they'll likely get answers for the wrong APIs and it doesn't help experts find questions to answer for the same reason.

[shader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shader) would be another possibly controversial example. Is it a GLSL shader? A HLSL shader? A SPIR-V shader? A Metal shader? A WGSL shader? A Renderman shader? Until I know have no clue if I can answer the question so a question with only tag [shader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shader) doesn't work.

Effectively if one of those was the only tag on the question no one would answer it and no one would look for it hence if fits the definition of a meta-tag because it can not work as the only tag on a question. A question about how to use textures in directx works with a [directx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/directx) by itself because a directx expert is likely to know about textures in directx. A question about how to use textures in directx with a [textures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/textures) by itself does not work because until I know the API I have no idea if I can help answer without reading the question first.

Are the tags above meta tags? If so, should we and/or S.O do more to follow the blog post above and discourage these meta tags? Should I go remove those tags from questions I just sampled? Am I misunderstanding the benefits of the tags above?

I feel almost like this leads to the conclusion is that the majority of tags should only be:

- The API/Library/Framework/Service/Software (eg: [directx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/directx), [react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/react), [tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tensorflow), [github-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/github-api), [electron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/electron), [emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/emacs))
- The language (eg: [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python), [ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby), [bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bash))
- The OS if it's OS specific (eg: [macos-catalina](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macos-catalina), [windows-10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-10), [ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios))

I'm sure that list is too small but I guess I'm confident at least that those things are useful tags for a question. I can be an expert on "react", an expert on "ruby", and an experienced "ios" developer. I can not be an expert on "sprite" or "simulator" or "texture"

I'm also wondering what, if anything S.O can do.

- Can they ban these meta tags so users can't submit a question with them and if they try then suggest better tags?

  Maybe like "Tag [2d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/2d) is considered not useful. Please tag with the language you're using and the API/Library/Framework/service your code is interacting with" and maybe based on the content of the question suggest some tags.
- Maybe poor tags should just be stripped period because seeing them just encourages more usage?

  Well if they were banned then at least it would stop new usage.
- Maybe users of a certain rep should be able to vote on a tag to be banned as a meta tag?

  5? votes and it's no longer allowed on new questions? I'm not sure enough people would vote to be effective but I'm fairly confident manually bringing up burnination candidates on meta is not an effective solution.

Comment: What about language-agnostic tags like `if-statement`, `for-loop`, `while-loop`, `arrays`, `null` and hundreds of others?

Comment: To me those are all meta tags as well. `array` is up there in the list from the 50 question. none of those tags stand on their own. They seem to fit the definition of meta tag

Comment: Closely related: [Nuke and blacklist all of the tags for fundamental programming concepts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/304229/4642212).

Comment: There is an actual definition of  meta-tag. It isn't given here or the linked post. But the linked post says "**The reason meta-tags are a problem is that they do not describe the *content* of the question**. They describe some other aspect of the question". A meta-tag is one that does not describe the content of the question. That is a per-question definition. The fact that a tag can be so misused does not make it a meta-tag. A tag that could only be used that way can reasonably be called a meta-tag independent of any use. A tag use reasonably describing content is OK.

Comment: The question should be is the tag useful. The tags I listed above are arguably not useful. Having [a list of questions tagged with "arrays"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arrays?tab=Newest) is arguably not useful, a waste of space, energy, and effort. If you want questions about arrays and some language [you can search for that](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+array). So the [tag:arrays] tag provides nothing useful. These tags instead [just links unrelated questions to each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/depth)

Comment: +1 for bringing up this. Some tags does really work bad alone, see e.g. [api] its description even starts with "DO NOT USE THIS TAG ALONE".