# Misspelled tag "finetunning"

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

The tag [finetunning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/finetunning) has 54 questions as of writing. The tag name is misspelled; it should be "fine-tuning". (Or deleted, I suppose.)

Comment: What exactly is the purpose of that tag?

Comment: It seems to be for questions about [fine-tuning of machine learning models](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/331369/what-is-meant-by-fine-tuning-of-neural-network). The tag doesn't have usage guidance but the questions do seem to be about that topic.

Comment: It seems to be a good way to track down low quality content if you ask me.

Comment: Well, the questions with that tag don't seem to be lacking upvotes. If you think they are low quality then I invite you to downvote them instead.

Comment: This is just a meta-tag and should be burninated.

Comment: I've burned down 15, but have to focus on other things. If it is still there when I have time again, I'll burn it down further, but feel free to just edit these posts and vote to close where appropriate. It's a very small number of posts now, just 39, so should be a breeze! Ask for help in the [SOCVR room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) if you need to muster closing support!

Comment: I agree that we should burninate this tag. It’s like [Nuke and blacklist all of the tags for fundamental programming concepts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/304229/4642212). “Fine tuning” is a fundamental concept of machine learning, so it’s too generic as a tag if the question already contains [tag:machine-learning] or a variant of that. It doesn’t really tell us what the question is about, other than machine learning, but there’s a tag for _that_.

Comment: ...and it's gone

Comment: I hate to spoil the fun here, but why are we not following the [burnination due process](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination?noredirect=1&lq=1) in this case? The tag had > 50 questions and unless anyone here has an "authoritative knowledge of all technologies relevant" (in which case I apologize) I am at a loss why there is no prior discussion

Comment: @OlegValter The tag failed all four criteria and was just a meta-tag rather than a language or ancillary language tag. Also, the 50 tag threshold was IIRC not meant as a hard and fast amount but rather an approximate benchmark. With mod support, I think something that's within 4 questions of the threshold is effectively the same as the threshold. It's a "know it when you see it" kind of judicial sliding scale.

Comment: @TylerH - although I understand what you are talking about, I still don't think we should go around preliminary discussion *especially* when there is mod support. At least providing the information on why all 4 criteria should be necessary when asking to do away with the tag and waiting at least a day for others to provide feedback (not everyone is in the same timezone as the asker) will only be beneficial for the community, it is unilateral decisions that are harmful. Did anyone consider asking feedback from the top answerer in the tag,  btw (who actually has at least bronze tags in ML)?

Comment: @OlegValter FWIW I'm just providing my perspective on why this was expedited; I wasn't involved with this tag removal at all. BTW, the fact this is a meta-tag of such an ambiguous name kind of removes any relevant for a "top answerer" or any such score that person might have in a random tag. I won't get in to how... debatable the topicality is of such use of this tag is for something like machine learning.

Comment: @TylerH - I know, I am doing the same here but from another perspective - since you are the only one who replied, I addressed you. I do not have anything against burning the tag, I just find that everything should follow due process - afaik, burnination criteria were created to help alleviate the problem of tag vigilantism. As for "top answerer" - I do not disagree, the point was to give a tag-to-be-burned a fair chance for defense ( just like being guilty of heinous crime does not mean we should skip the trial in court ), though.