# The [simplify] tag is simply bad

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request, tag-disambiguation

The [simplify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/simplify) tag has 672 questions and 8 watchers. The tag info and wiki say:

> This tag refers to the process of making something simpler or smaller in order to increase its efficiency, usability, or operation speed.
>
> Use this tag for questions related to making something simpler or smaller in order to increase its efficiency, usability, or operation speed. Note however that questions related to simplifying working code will be better suited on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

There is also a [simplification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/simplification) tag, with 228 questions, 1 watcher, and no tag info or wiki.

Both tags attract a mix of questions about different things:

1. Many of the questions are open-ended "how can this (working) code be simplified?" questions, which are not even on-topic for Stack Overflow; many of these *might* be on-topic for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), but many are also too low-quality for either Stack Overflow or Code Review.
2. Many are about algebraic simplification of mathematical expressions, using symbolic mathematics libraries such as [sympy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sympy). While this arguably falls into the broad description from the tag info, questions on this topic require different expertise to answer so it doesn't seem useful for them to be grouped into the same tag as questions about simplifying source code.
3. There are some about simplifying code where the code involved is just one specific fragment, or otherwise the criteria for what "simplifying" means are specific enough, so the question is on-topic and not "too broad", and can have objective answers. For example, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57157372/is-there-a-way-to-shorten-this-while-condition) seems fine, and has a net +52 votes.

It seems like a clean-up is in order. I propose:

- Questions like 1. should be closed as "needs more focus", with a comment pointing at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) **if** the question would be suitable there.
- Questions like 2. should get a tag like [algebraic-simplification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/algebraic-simplification), [mathematical-simplification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mathematical-simplification) or [expression-simplification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/expression-simplification) so they can be clearly distinguished. I'm not sure what the best tag name would be.
- The [simplify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/simplify) and [simplification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/simplification) tags should be merged and kept for questions like 3., and perhaps renamed to something like [code-simplification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-simplification) so that the tag is less likely to be incorrectly used for questions like 2.

Possibly also related is the [one-liner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/one-liner) tag, but I don't want to make this meta question too broad. What are people's thoughts?

Comment: "There are some about simplifying code where the code involved is just one specific fragment, or otherwise the criteria for what "simplifying" means are specific enough," why there should be a tag about that? Who does it benefit? If I know nothing about the language, I won't be able to answer it, so who is the population target?

Comment: @Braiam Well, there are other tags like [tag:arrays] which are usually only useful in combination with a specific language tag, for the same reason. But perhaps you're right that it is not useful as a tag regardless.

Comment: We often wish for a simple algorithm, but can't find one , so a question about a simplfication is necessary

Comment: Which is wrong. See [previous discussions.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/304229/792066) The tag should be able to work as the only tag on the question and describe the question accurately, if it doesn't it shouldn't exist in the first place. Tags are not hashtags.

Comment: Could some of the questions be retagged [refactoring]?

Comment: @Braiam there are a lot of tags that don't work very well on their own - [tag:sql] questions often need a DBMS tag to go along with it because of subtle differences in language between platforms. I think in this case the use of the tag is to divide "it doesn't work and I need help making it work" from "it works but I know there must be a better way" questions, different users with knowledge on the matching language etc tags may be more or less likely to put their time into those different situations depending on their own strengths.

Comment: @Andrew I believe that's why codereview.stackexchange exists

Comment: @Andrew and none of them should exist. The first question you should ask when you create a tag is "your question covers a new topic that nobody else has asked about before on this site". I've rarely seen that for many tags brought up in meta, where another tag already covers the topic succinctly. The fact that they exist is just a testament of our failure to correctly police tag creation.

Comment: @mjr There's a lot of overlap between stack exchange sites, just because a question fits perfectly into a more narrow site doesn't make it off topic on all others, code review is probably a better place for such questions, but they are still on topic here.

Comment: I think that the tags should all be reviewed before being added so that duplicates can be spotted

Comment: There was a discussion in 2018 when excel-vba was removed and turned into just vba. The consensus was that VBA is not useful on its own, but would be paired with powerpoint, word, or excel, making it useful because of vast language differences. This seems no different to me. There's precedent for tags not standing on their own.

Comment: @mm4096 https://stackoverflow.com/tags?page=1&tab=popular There are only 1834 pages of tags to review. Be sure to let us know when you're done so we know when we can start adding tags again ;-P.

Comment: @HereticMonkey ok good point

Comment: @HereticMonkey Challange kinda accepted. Be finished in about 10 years